# Add rows to a table from another table using Common table expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

For example, I have the first table and I want to fill the second table using the first table.

```
           Table A              
 Name   A    B   C   D
-----------------------
 name1  a1  b1  c1  d1
 name2  a2  b2  c2  d2



      Table B (Desired Format)      
  ID    Name    Code
 ----------------------
  1     name1   a1
  2     name1   b1
  3     name1   c1
  4     name1   d1
  5     name2   a2
  6     name2   b2
  7     name2   c2
  8     name2   d2
```

As per the suggestions of @Surendra Nath GM, I tried this

```
   DECLARE @counter as int
   SET @counter = 1;
  ;WITH Actual AS 
  (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY) as ID  FROM Northwind.dbo.Table1
  WHERE 
   ),FIRST AS
  (
  SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-3) AS ID,Name, A 
  FROM Northwind.dbo.Table1

   ),SECOND AS
  (
   SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-2) AS ID, Name ,B
  from Northwind.dbo.Table1
   ), NEXT AS
  (
 SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-1) AS ID, Name, C
  from Northwind.dbo.Table1next
 ), ________ as
 (
  SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4) AS ID, Name, D
from Northwind.dbo.Table1
 )

 @counter = @counter+1;
  )
  SELECT * FROM FIRST
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM SECOND
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM NEXT
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM _________
  ORDER BY ID
```

Here, what do I use after the "SECOND AS". I tried writing "THIRD AS" but apparently no such command exists so after some searching, I could write the third row using "NEXT AS" but I am completely clueless as to how do I insert the Fourth row.

I know I can simply write 4 insert commands for each of A,B,C and D but then I will get the not codes in the following order which is NOT desired:

```
Table B(NOT DESIRED IN THIS FORMAT)     
  ID    Name    Code
 ----------------------
  1     name1   a1
  2     name2   a2
  3     name1   b1
  4     name2   b2
  5     name1   c1
  6     name2   c2
  7     name1   d1
  8     name2   d2
```

Also, the desired format can be achieved using simple loops but in the project I am working on, there are around 200000 rows and the simple loops method takes a lot of time. So, I want to do it using CTE. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unpivot` is probably the fastest (best performing) way to do this:

```
insert into b(id, name, code)
    select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id, name, code
    from t
    unpivot (code for col in (A, B, C, D)) unpvt;
```

This calculates the `id` using `row_number()`.  I would advise you to set this column up as an `identity` column instead, when you define the table.

EDIT:

This doesn't guarantee that the id numbers are in the right order.  If they are in the right order, that is a coincidence.  You can get any order you want by using the right `order by` clause in the select and ordering by that:

```
insert into b(id, name, code)
    select row_number() over (order by (select name, col)) as id, name, code
    from t
    unpivot (code for col in (A, B, C, D)) unpvt;
```

You might have another key on each row, other than name, that is better than the name.  This also orders the columns alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Didn't know about the unpivot method

Comment: Interesting, but how does this guarantee ordering of the ID numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert  TableB
        (ID, Name, Code)
select  row_number() over (order by Name, Code)
,       Name
,       Code
from    (
        select  Name
        ,       A as Code
        from    TableA
        union all
        select  Name
        ,       B
        from    TableA
        union all
        select  Name
        ,       C
        from    TableA
        union all
        select  Name
        ,       D
        from    TableA
        ) SubQueryAlias
```